# AngularJS - How to show custom directives based on condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to show a custom directive (i.e. task-moveable) based on some condition. I have to only show the task-movable attribute for tasks which is not completed yet. Is there any way we can do this in Angularjs?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="gantt-body-background" ng-repeat="row in gantt.rows" task-moveable>
  ....
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a tweak such that your `taskMoveable` directive can observe a value assigned to it.  From there do an `$eval` on the value of the `taskMoveable` attribute to get your boolean.

As an example:

```
app.directive('taskMoveable', function () {
  return {
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.taskMoveable = {};

      $attrs.$observe('taskMoveable', function (value) {
        if (value) {
          $scope.taskMoveable.amIMoveable = $scope.$eval(value);
        }
      });
    },
    template: '<span ng-bind="taskMoveable.amIMoveable"></span>'
  };
});
```

See my plunk here for a more detailed example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/0nK4K9j3SmNnz8PgRYfR

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-if for that whole element. Something like this.

```
<div class="gantt-body-background" ng-repeat="row in gantt.rows" ng-if="thing.stuff" task-moveable>
  ....
</div>
```

Then that div would only be in the DOM if thing.stuff was truthy.

Comment: If I do that the entire div will go off in case of false condition. I don't want to do that. Actually I want to show/hide the "task-moveable" custom attribute based on the boolean condition.